# Capture audio phonegap 3.0 without interface

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have gotten audio recording to work on Phonegap 3.0, however depending on the platform it launches a custom interface that facilitates the recording.

Is there a way to not show the interface but use a custom interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

Instead of using the capture API, use the media api.

```
    function recordAudio() {
    var src = "myrecording.mp3";
    var mediaRec = new Media(src,
        // success callback
        function() {
            console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
        },

        // error callback
        function(err) {
            console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: "+ err.code);
        });

    // Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for videos?