# Phonegap Media API - Record and Play Audio - Android

Tags: android, cordova, media, record

I'm hoping to record some audio and then have the ability to play it back. Its important for me to be able to [customize the record interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542547/capture-audio-phonegap-3-0-without-interface).

In the below example after recording I get a duration of -1 and no audio is played.

**Step 1.**
Added [Media Plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_media_media.md.html)

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media
```

**Step 2.** My Code

Note src is "amr" as requested from docs.

> Android devices record audio in Adaptive Multi-Rate format. The
>   specified file should end with a .amr extension.

However, "myrecording.amr" does not exist in my file structure as I'm hoping it will be created.

**Javascript**

```
var data = {
  rec: ""
};
$scope.record = function(){
    console.log('record');
    var src = "myrecording.amr";
    data.rec = new Media(src,
    function() {
      console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
    },

    function(err) {
      console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: "+ err.code);
    });

    data.rec.startRecord();
}

$scope.stopRecording = function(){
    console.log('stop');
    data.rec.stopRecord();
}

$scope.playRecording = function(){
    console.log('play');
    data.rec.play();
}

$scope.logDuration = function(){
    console.log(data.rec.getDuration());
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="record()">Record</button>
<button ng-click="stopRecording()">Stop Record</button>
<button ng-click="playRecording()">Play Record</button>
<button ng-click="logDuration()">Log Duration</button>
```

**Output From Above**

No audio is played when I click play.

```
0     999846   log      record
1     001845   log      stop
2     002000   log      recordAudio():Audio Success
3     004657   log      play
4     008989   log      -1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I can answer any questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are my steps for getting this to work.

## 1. Run these commands

```
ionic start RecordTest blank
ionic platform add ios
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media
```

## 2. Create `RecordTest/www/myrecording.wav`

## 3. Paste the below code in `RecordTest/www/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <!-- <script src="js/app.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Record audio
    // 
    function recordAudio() {
        var src = "myrecording.wav";
        var mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

        // Record audio
        mediaRec.startRecord();

        // Stop recording after 10 sec
        var recTime = 0;
        var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
            recTime = recTime + 1;
            setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");
            if (recTime >= 3) {
                clearInterval(recInterval);
                mediaRec.stopRecord();
                mediaRec.play();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        recordAudio();
    }

    // onSuccess Callback
    //
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
    }

    // onError Callback 
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    // Set audio position
    // 
    function setAudioPosition(position) {
        document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
          <title>Device Properties Example</title>
          <!-- <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script> -->
          <p id="media">Recording audio...</p>
          <p id="audio_position"></p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

## 4. Run `ionic emulate ios`

The above should work.

**Note: the extension changes depending on the platform you're developing for**

Comment: Hi, I have a question. You added the ios here and not Android. So this is about ios recording?

Comment: I don't think it works in android. Only .amr format is supported when recording.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with something similar with ionicframworkf and phonegap plugins.. I build a Record Factory for:

startRecord, stopRecord, playRecord and Save record to the server... This is my factory file:

```
 /**
 * Record service
 * @module record
 * @author Claudio A. Marrero
 * @class famvoice
 */
 services.factory('$record', [

  '$rootScope',
  '$socket',
  '$account',

  function($rootScope, $socket, $account) {

    var enumerator = 0;
    var recordName = 'record-'+enumerator+'.mp3';
    var mediaRec = null;
    var OnCallback = null;
    var OnAppendData = {};

    /**
    * Start a record
    *
    * @method startRecord
    */
    function startRecord(){
      enumerator++;
      recordName = 'record-'+enumerator+'.mp3';
      mediaRec = new Media(recordName,
          function() {
          },
          function(err) {
          });
      mediaRec.startRecord();
    }

    /**
    * Stop record
    *
    * @method stopRecord
    */
    function stopRecord(){
      mediaRec.stopRecord();
    }

    /**
    * Stop record
    *
    * @method stopRecord
    */
    function playRecord(){
      mediaRec.play();
    }

    /**
    * Get the name of the record
    *
    * @method getRecord
    */
    function getRecord(){
      return recordName;
    }

    /**
    * Save the recorded file to the server
    *
    * @method save
    */
    function save(callback,appendData){
      OnCallback = callback;
      OnAppendData = appendData;
      window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, OnFileSystem, fail);
    }

    /**
    * Callback for setting the file system to persistent.
    *
    * @method OnFileSystem
    */
    function OnFileSystem(fileSystem){
      fileSystem.root.getFile(recordName, null, OnGetFile, fail);
    }

    /**
    * Callback for geting the file for disk
    *
    * @method OnGetFile
    */
    function OnGetFile(fileEntry){
      fileEntry.file(OnFileEntry, fail);
    }

    /**
    * Callback for file entry, this get the file.
    *
    * @method OnFileEntry
    */
    function OnFileEntry(file){
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function(evt) {

          var image = evt.target.result;
          var base64Data  =   image.replace(/^data:audio\/mpeg;base64,/, "");
          base64Data  +=  base64Data.replace('+', ' ');

          $socket.emit('playlists:file',{file:base64Data,name:recordName, token: $account.token(), info:OnAppendData},OnCallback);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    /**
    * When any process of saving file fail, this console the error.
    *
    * @method OnFileEntry
    */
    function fail(err){
      console.log('Error');
      console.log(err);
    }

    /**
    * Play record
    *
    * @method playRecord
    */
    function playRecord(){
      var mediaFile = new Media(recordName,
          function() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
          },
          function(err) {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: "+err);
          }
      );
      // Play audio
      mediaFile.play();
    }

  return {
    start: startRecord,
    stop: stopRecord,
    play:playRecord,
    name:getRecord,
    save:save
  };
}]);
```

My project is on GitHub if you want to check how I implement this factory:

https://github.com/cmarrero01/famvoice

You will need to checkout the development branch.

I hope that is ussesful for you. :)

PH: I notice this question on codementor request, but I'm not a good english speaker. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I glanced over this briefly and when I dive into it I'll let you know if it worked. You're the best!

Comment: Your welcome :). Check my project on githup, I'm sure that it will usedfull for you. :).

Comment: Not sure if the repo is up to date. I only see two commits inside of it.
"070c0dc Init apps, init server, folders structure.
0c3de11 Initial commit."

However, the file posted above is helpful, I'll see if I can get that working.

Comment: Hi Daniel, you need to checkout the "development" branch, I'm not have enought time to make a release yet. But the record actions is working on that branch. Clone the repo, and make git checkout development to switch to that branch.

Comment: Not sure why that did occur to me. I see it now. Thank you. I'll try it tonight.

Comment: Thanks so much again. This really helped me get unstuck. I ended up getting the example from cordova working. I'm going to structure my factory just like your sample above. What is your hackhands? URL I'll favorite you.

Comment: Very good Daniel, your welcome. If you need some help with your projects don't heistate to get in touch. My little blog is claudiomarrero.wordpress.com.